# cropping an image with respect to co ordinates selected

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I am having an input image like this

[image]

Cropping the redpoints is easy since its a rectangle. How can i crop if the red point on 2,3,6 and 7 are moved to green points dynamically. These points may change how can i crop dynamically in program.

The result may look like this

[image]

I tried Warppperspective but i was unable to get expected result.
The program was like this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('sudoku_result.png')

pts1 = np.float32([[100,60],[260,60],[100,180],[260,180],[100,300],[260,300]])
pts2 = np.float32([[20,60],[340,60],[60,180],[300,180][100,300],[260,300]])

M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1,pts2)
dst = cv2.warpPerspective(img,M,(360,360))


plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(img),plt.title('Input')
plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(dst),plt.title('Output')
plt.show()
```

I am new to image processing an would like to know which is the best method.

Comment: don't ask for best methods. no one knows how you define best and everybody has his own understanding of best....

can you provide a picture that shows how your cropped image should look like? will it contain the sudoku cells? or only the stuff between those coordinates? do you want to strech the selection to fill a rectangle or should the cropped stuff on a black background for example?

Comment: @Piglet  Stretching the selection to rectangle a rectangle will be good

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Crop the enclosing rectangle the one created by (minX,minY,maxX,maxY) and then for each pixel in the cropped image you can check if the point inside the polygon created by the original points or not and for the points outside the original shape you put zero.

The code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read a image
I = cv2.imread('i.png')

# Define the polygon coordinates to use or the crop
polygon = [[[20,110],[450,108],[340,420],[125,420]]]

# First find the minX minY maxX and maxY of the polygon
minX = I.shape[1]
maxX = -1
minY = I.shape[0]
maxY = -1
for point in polygon[0]:

    x = point[0]
    y = point[1]

    if x < minX:
        minX = x
    if x > maxX:
        maxX = x
    if y < minY:
        minY = y
    if y > maxY:
        maxY = y

# Go over the points in the image if thay are out side of the emclosing rectangle put zero
# if not check if thay are inside the polygon or not
cropedImage = np.zeros_like(I)
for y in range(0,I.shape[0]):
    for x in range(0, I.shape[1]):

        if x < minX or x > maxX or y < minY or y > maxY:
            continue

        if cv2.pointPolygonTest(np.asarray(polygon),(x,y),False) >= 0:
            cropedImage[y, x, 0] = I[y, x, 0]
            cropedImage[y, x, 1] = I[y, x, 1]
            cropedImage[y, x, 2] = I[y, x, 2]

# Now we can crop again just the envloping rectangle
finalImage = cropedImage[minY:maxY,minX:maxX]

cv2.imwrite('finalImage.png',finalImage)
```

The final image:

[image]

If you want to stretch the croped image

```
# Now strectch the polygon to a rectangle. We take the points that
polygonStrecth = np.float32([[0,0],[finalImage.shape[1],0],[finalImage.shape[1],finalImage.shape[0]],[0,finalImage.shape[0]]])

# Convert the polygon corrdanite to the new rectnagle
polygonForTransform = np.zeros_like(polygonStrecth)
i = 0
for point in polygon[0]:

    x = point[0]
    y = point[1]

    newX = x - minX
    newY = y - minY

    polygonForTransform[i] = [newX,newY]
    i += 1


# Find affine transform
M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(np.asarray(polygonForTransform).astype(np.float32), np.asarray(polygonStrecth).astype(np.float32))

# Warp one image to the other
warpedImage = cv2.warpPerspective(finalImage, M, (finalImage.shape[1], finalImage.shape[0]))
cv2.imshow('a',warpedImage)
```

[image]

Comment: But the coordinates change dynamically we cant define a polygon and need to stretch it to fit the square

Comment: So what if they change dynamically? every time they change you run the function with the new coordinate and get the new view.

Comment: How to make that cropped polygon fit to the rectangle like stretching or something?

Comment: I don't understand do you want to stretch the rectangle to the trapezoid or you want to crop the original image once as a rectangle and when the shape change to the trapezoid  according to the trapezoid?

Comment: its like what you did stretch the trapezoid to fit into a rectangle. But i found that findHomography along with warpperspective will be a better way to do the same. Thanks for the solution this works :)

Comment: I am looking for exactly the same thing but for the android java version. Is there any link I could follow for reference? 
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the co-ordinates you mentioned aren't accurate. So tweaking the coordinates to match the shape and using the Cloudinary distort function complemented by custom shapes cropping, here's the result:

http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/fetch/e_distort:20:60:450:60:340:410:140:410,l_sample,fl_cutter,g_north_west/e_trim/https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGSKW.png

If you'd like play around with these Cloudinary functions, here are some samples:
http://cloudinary.com/blog/how_to_dynamically_distort_images_to_fit_your_graphic_design
http://cloudinary.com/cookbook/custom_shapes_cropping